# Pyglet detect when a key has not been pressed the previous frame

Tags: input, python-3.6, keyboard-events, pyglet

I am currently making a game in pyglet and I have my key input setup like this:

```
def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
    try:
        del self.keys[symbol]
    except:
        pass

def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.ESCAPE:  # [ESC]
        self.alive = 0
    self.keys[symbol] = True
```

And I need to be able to detect when a player is first pressing the key rather than holding it down. For example, I have tried this:

```
def update(self, keys, dt):
    if (key.UP in keys) & (key.UP not in self.prev_keys):
        jump()
self.prev_keys = keys
```

But they are always equal no matter what happens. I can't detect when they first hold the key down. If you need more information about what i am trying to do or how my code is currently set up, just ask. Thank you for the help!

EDIT: Okay, I figured out what my problem was. In addition to Torxed's answer below (about the use of & vs. and) my main issue was that the dictionary objects were linked. So, instead of `self.prev_keys = keys` I need to use `self.prev_keys = keys.copy()`. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem as me!

Comment: Fun to see that [my code](https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/blob/master/python/pyglet_base.py#L27) is in use. The way you can solve this is to put the jump logic in `key_down`, that's the quickest solution. The second and better would be a bit more elaborate, where you implement what you're trying to implement, a secondary map over which keys have been `self.processed_keys` for instance. Is the indentation of `self.prev_keys` wrong or is it actually outside the `update()` function?

Comment: @Torxed Thank you so much for the response! Earlier I was trying to figure out Object-Based for piglet and I found your response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253823/pyglet-into-class/48254358?r=SearchResults#48254358). It was incredibly helpful so thank you so so much for this response and your other responses. You have been really helpful while I learn piglet so thank you!

Comment: Bloody hell, think I figured out your main issue while over-complicating the solution haha. Oh boy, to much PHP/Javascript these last few months. Solution below.

Answer (score 1):

So, your main issue is *probably* the use of `&` instead of `and` here:

```
if (key.UP in keys) & (key.UP not in self.prev_keys):
```

Because [bitwise AND *(`&`)*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) is not the same as [AND operator *(`and`)*](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_oper_logical1). The `&` actually compares on a bit level if one or more `1`'s align up against each other. here's a simplified example of how [binary numbers](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) work and how the [bitwise AND *(`&`)*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) works with/on them:

```
00000001  # Value 1
00000011  # Value 3
```

Doing `1 & 3` would result in `1` because on a bit-level, the `1`'s are on the same "location". Where as the following example:

```
00000001  # Value 1
00000100  # Value 4
```

Doing `1 & 4` would result in `0` because the `1`'s down align up.

You're trying to compare if both if statements are true `if (...) and (...)` by using the bit-level-comparator. Which won't work. So the solution here would be to do:

```
if (key.UP in keys) and (key.UP not in self.prev_keys):
```

So the code might look something like:

```py
from pyglet import *
from pyglet.gl import *

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.keys = {}
        self.processed_keys = {}

        self.mouse_x = 0
        self.mouse_y = 0

        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.mouse_x = x

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        try:
            del self.keys[symbol]
        except:
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

        self.keys[symbol] = True

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        ## Add stuff you want to render here.
        ## Preferably in the form of a batch.

        self.flip()

    def jump(self):
        print('Jumped, yaay!')

    def update(self):
        if (key.UP in self.keys) and (key.UP not in self.processed_keys):
            self.jump()

        self.processed_keys = {**self.keys}

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.update()
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = main()
    x.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely was an error that I needed to fix, but it didn’t actually help my problem (although I would have needed to fix this at some point) because when I would try debugging by printing when it was the start of a new loop and then the two dictionaries for keys and previous keys they would always be exactly the same. I think I’ll go with an approach where I have a handled keys dict instead of previous keys. Then I can remove a key from it when I actually handle it for the first time. Thank you for the help!